# Cascading update using update trigger in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm using following code to update foreign key value in `Residence` table on update of `ProvinceID`, but I get this error:

> update statement conflicted with reference constraint "FK_Residence_Province". The conflict occurred in database '', table "dbo,Residences", column "ResidenceState".

Code:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[UPOnProvinceDelete] 
ON [seniors].[dbo].[Provinces] 
FOR UPDATE AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF UPDATE([ProvinceID])
    BEGIN
       UPDATE seniors.dbo.Residences
       SET [Residences].[ResidenceState] = inserted.[ProvinceID]
       FROM [Residences], deleted, inserted
       WHERE deleted.[ProvinceID]= [Residences].[ResidenceState]
         AND deleted.[ProvinceID]= inserted.[ProvinceID]
    END;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here - We know from the where clause that `deleted.ProvinceID` and `inserted.ProvinceID` are equal, and that `Residences.ResidenceState` and `deleted.ProvinceID` are equal - so the `SET` clause is effectively performing a no-op.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: on update provinceId, i want to update that id in residence table also using trigger.But as u are saying that deleted.ProvinceID and inserted.ProvinceID will be same than how to differentiate both?